# How to change the value or a string inside the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to find the exact value of what is giving the API which is b string and modify the value of it

```
const arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

For example I want to modify the "b" string to "d" string. But the API is giving a limited string and I want to find if there's a 'b' string then modify it

Comment: ok. so what is the problem and where is the code ?

Comment: I want to modify  this array `const arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]` and modify the "b" string to "d" string. But the API is giving a limited string and I want to find if there's a 'b' string then modify it

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+change+string+in+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I'll do that thank you

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but can you not just do :

```
arr[1]=arr[3]
```

Because `arr` then becomes: `['a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'e']`.
If you want to first error check that `arr` has a value at `'d'` (ie `arr.length !< 4`), you could do:
`arr[1]= arr.length > 3  ? arr[3] :arr[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information given, I believe you want to do

```js
const arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
const idx = arr.indexOf("b");
if (idx !== -1) arr[idx]="d";
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use your custom function. when ever APIcall completed you have to check if there is "b" inside array just get the index and change it to "d"

```
var index = arraysOfElementFromBackend.indexOf("b");
if (index !== -1) {
    arraysOfElementFromBackend[index] = "d";
}
```